# PHP list highlight current item

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a ul list that is rendered in PHP and I am trying to highlight the current selected item. The code is part of a tag sorting jquery portfolio. I have tried to add a current class to the li element but that only works for the default element "All".

PHP-code

```
if ($unique_tags_arr) {
            echo '<ul class="jquery">';
            echo '<li data-filter=".filterable">';
            echo "All";
            echo '</li>';
            foreach ($unique_tags_arr as &$value) {
                echo '<li data-filter=".'.str_replace(' ', '', $value). " " .'"> '.$value.'</li>'; 

            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the selected item value stored anywhere? POST, GET, session or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "ul.jquery > li", function() {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    jQuery(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
                    $this.addClass("highlight");
                });
```

and then write a css rule for the highlight class

Comment: This worked like a charm! But is there any way I can sett the "All" tag as the .highlight the first time you enter the page?

Comment: Disregard that last question! Feel pretty stupid that I didnt figure that one out right away. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following css style.

```
.jquery li:hover
{
    color: #000;
    background: #fff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's no page load when filtering because your list items have the data-filter attribute and therefore I'd guess it's using jQuery. Then you should use something like gbestard suggested.

But if there's page load and you are using PHP on this like your tags say... You'll need the selected item value stored somewhere (POST, GET etc.) and with your stored selected item you need to compare if any of the array items has the same value and if it is, just add class "selected".

This is with GET so your selected value would be in the url.

```
$active = $_GET['selected_filter'];

if ($unique_tags_arr) {
    echo '<ul class="jquery">';
    echo '<li data-filter=".filterable">';
    echo "All";
    echo '</li>';
    foreach ($unique_tags_arr as &$value) {
        echo '<li data-filter="'.str_replace(' ', '', $value).'" ';
        if ($value == $active) { echo 'class="selected"'; }
        echo '> '.$value.'</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Then just give styles to the .selected class.

Comment: This resulted in the sorting not working. Only the all tag was playing nice.